# How can a join table be part of an ON DELETE CASCADE cycle?

Tags: sql, sql-server, cascade

In SQL Server I have a simple database schema, where Authors and Books have a many-many join table, and both have foreign keys to Publishers.

I am not allowed to set ON CASCADE DELETE on all the relations:

[image: Database schema with error]

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_Books_Publishers'.
> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Books_Publishers' on table 'Books' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
> Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

What's the cycle here? Don't cascade cycles end at join tables as they have no foreign keys referencing them?

Or is it that deleting a Publisher may give two causes for deleting a BookAuthor row (via Authors or via Books)? And why would that be a problem?

---

This is the DDL for the above:

```sql
USE [fk-test]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Authors]    Script Date: 3-6-2022 15:23:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PublisherId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Authors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[BookAuthor]    Script Date: 3-6-2022 15:23:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BookAuthor](
    [BookId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AuthorId] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Books]    Script Date: 3-6-2022 15:23:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Books](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PublisherId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Books] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Publishers]    Script Date: 3-6-2022 15:23:22 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Publishers](
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Publishers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, OPTIMIZE_FOR_SEQUENTIAL_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Authors]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Authors_Authors] FOREIGN KEY([PublisherId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Publishers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Authors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Authors_Authors]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BookAuthor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BookAuthor_Authors] FOREIGN KEY([AuthorId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Authors] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BookAuthor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BookAuthor_Authors]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BookAuthor]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_BookAuthor_Books] FOREIGN KEY([BookId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Books] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[BookAuthor] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_BookAuthor_Books]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Books]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Books_Publishers] FOREIGN KEY([PublisherId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Publishers] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Books] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Books_Publishers]
GO
```

Comment: Why do you need PublisherId in the Authors table?

Comment: This is a simplified, made up example. Here you could imagine that each author is signed up with one publisher (but can collaborate on books with authors from other publishers). In my real data model there are a bunch more tables in between and there are good real-world reasons why this shape exists.

Comment: What action you have applied in `ON DELETE` clause in `Authors` Table?

Comment: All `ON DELETE CASCADE`. It is my understanding that for Authors that means any BookAuthor rows referencing it would be deleted too.

Comment: _What's the cycle here?_ What does it matter? The engine won't let you do this - find a different path forward. If you search on that error you will many discussions and discover that the database engine is very simplistic and pessimistic in this regard.

Comment: Please include the DDL so we can reproduce the case. There's no cycle in there as far as I can tell from the image.

Comment: Good point, I've added the DDL as generated by SSMS (including the problematic final constraint)

Answer (score 0):

It's because there'd be two cascading delete paths from Publisher to BookAuthor,one via Author and one via Books.

A solutions is to modify the two foreign keys

```
FK_Authors_Authors
FK_Books_Publishers
```

to

```
ON DELETE SET NULL
```

And make PublisherId in Books and Authors nullable.

Then you'll need to do your own custom cascade delete code when deleting a publisher.  e.g delete the publisher, then delete the relevant Authors and Books.